# Sending many requests in one websocket connection without reconnect

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

My python program work so slow, because make socket reconnect for any request. I want make one connect and send request, with out reconnect

My functions in file `send_by_socket.py`, some other function and class call `send_to_socket` for send logmessage. Now it work, but very slow. Reason  - make new connect for any message. I want single connection or poll for use it without reconnect. How make it, possibel have good example with sourcecode?

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
from logging import StreamHandler
import json


async def async_send(message):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://****.com/chat') as web_socket:
        await web_socket.send(message)


class WebSocketHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):

        msg = json.dumps({'log': {'message': record.message, 'date': record.asctime, 'level': record.levelname}})
        try:
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_send(msg))
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            pass


def send_to_socket(msg_dict):
    msg = json.dumps(msg_dict)
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_send(msg))
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        pass
```

Now program spend about **1 - 1.2** sec for request. I try

```py
con = websockets.connect('wss://****.com/chat')
con.send('some thing')
```

but have error *AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'send'*

Comment: wss  protocol is for https have you tried using ws   ?  which works on http ... I suggest you get it working using http and ws then once its working move to https and wss

Comment: Use ws it no way. Need wss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python
import asyncio
import websockets
from logging import StreamHandler
import json
import time


def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}

    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance


@singleton
class SendToWebSocket:
    """
    Send message in  web-socket, use one connection for sending.
    Try make new connection, if  old is lost.
    """
    __ws = None
    __url = "wss://***.com/chat"

    def __init__(self):
        self.retryTime = 0
        self.retryRepeat = 30
        self.__create_connect()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def __create_connect(self):
        if (time.time() - self.retryTime) > self.retryRepeat:
            try:
                self.__ws = yield from websockets.connect(self.__url)
                self.retryTime = 0
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                self.retryTime = time.time()

    def send(self, message):
        t = type(message)
        if t is dict:
            msg = json.dumps(message)
        elif t is str:
            msg = message
        else:
            raise ValueError("Message must be str or dict. Received %s" % type(t))
        if self.__ws is not None:
            try:
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.__async_send(msg))
                # print('Send normal')
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                # print("Can't send")
                # try recreate connect
                self.__create_connect()
        else:
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.__create_connect())

    async def __async_send(self, message):
        await self.__ws.send(message)


class WebSocketHandler(StreamHandler):
    """Custom handler for logging library"""

    def __init__(self):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self.web_socket = SendToWebSocket()

    def emit(self, record):

        msg = json.dumps({'log': {'message': record.message, 'date': record.asctime, 'level': record.levelname}})
        try:
            self.web_socket.send(msg)
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            pass
```